# 'Selected items changed to deselected' event in WinForm list view

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

Does Winform ListView control has such an event, that fires when 'all selected items changed to deselected'? So, when I have some selected items in the list and all changes to deselected (so, now I don't have any selected items) I should catch an event. I am afraid there is no built in event for it (?) Or...?

Comment: It does not. Just as it does not have an event that fires when all odd rows are selected. As mentioned by people who answered the question ItemSelectionChanged is the simplest way to perform this task. What do you have against a simple "if" statement?

Answer (score 1):

On the ItemSelectionChanged, check if any item is checked in the ListView:

```
listView1.ItemSelectionChanged += listView1_ItemSelectionChanged;

void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        //Do something
}
```

Comment: Not a good solution for me: it always fires when you just select another list item, not only when simply all items became deselected.

Comment: That's why the if-statement is there... Otherwise write your own control derived from the ListView with an event for when all items are deselected. But I guess the solution I gave is still the simplest one!

Answer (score 0):

You could use SelectedIndexChanged and in the event check if all items are deselected ie..

```
    bool allDeselected = true;

    foreach (ListViewItem item in myListView.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            allDeselected = false;
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a good solution for me: it always fires when you just select another list item, not only when simply all items became deselected.

Answer (score -1):

```
   this.listView1.ItemSelectionChanged += this.HandleOnListViewItemSelectionChanged;

    private void HandleOnListViewItemSelectionChanged(Object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            //do your selected work
        }
        else
        {
            //do your unselected work
            this.listView1.ItemSelectionChanged-= new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(this.listView1_ItemSelectionChanged);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It does not fire e.g. when items are deselected by clicking another list on the form and similar cases.

Comment: I don't think you should use e.IsSelected because if you have three items selected and deselect them all at once, the event is fired three times..

Comment: @Abbas: thanks for pointing out the problm, i made some tweak, i guess still it wont work